# How would i implement a next page in django

Tags: python, django, web

So I'm creating a web application and I have a section where I get data from the database through a view, I was wondering if the data exceeds 100 e.g profiles is there a way to implement a next page button which carries on the profiles e.g limit it to 5 profiles per page.

any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Yes :) Simply use django pagination.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/pagination/#example this is a very simple example how you can do that

Answer (score 0):

Django Side :

```
from django.core.paginator import Paginator

from django.shortcuts import render


def viewprofile(request):

   profile_details = Profile.objects.all()

   paginator = Paginator(profile_details, 5) # So limited to 5 profiles in a page


   page = request.GET.get('page')

   profile= paginator.get_page(page) #data

   return render(request, 'profile.html', {'profiles': profile}
```

Now we access this in html page :

```
  {% for profile in profiles %}
      {# Here we can display profile details  #}
  {% endfor %}

<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if profiles.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page=1">&laquo; first</a>
            <a href="?page={{ profiles.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ profiles.number }} of {{ profiles.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if profiles.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ profiles.next_page_number }}">next</a>
            <a href="?page={{ profiles.paginator.num_pages }}">last &raquo;</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a lot of code with not much teaching. Can you explain why this answers the question asked?

Comment: Next and Previous Button required and Limit the contents per page , this can done using pagination , its the process of separating digital content into discrete pages ..Django framework provides few classes that help you manage paginated data , that’s split across several pages, with “Previous/Next” links , The Above code is simple so any one can easily understand who know django